# Area graph acting differently in powerbi?

Tags: powerbi

When I am choosing particular years from the filter in some pages it is working fine.

But on some pages after choosing the particular years, Its showing result for those chosen years but its showing rest other years also.

Please help me to find out the possible reason why this is happening?

Please see the screenshots:

[image: reference]

1. First one is showing a straight line for all unselected years
2. Second graph (Number of Application Overtime (gender) is working fine.

Comment: Hmm it does look weird! There are a few things that might be worth checking (it's quite a challenging question without having access to the report). 1) Is X-axis using exactly the same date field on both charts? 2) On the 1st chart, are you using a measure or a simple table filed? Perhaps your measure is returning zeros instead of blanks. 3) Your "Year to View" slicer and 1st chart fields - are they somehow linked in the data model? 4) If all of this fails, is there any small data example that you can provide us so that we can recreate the issue?

Comment: Thank you so much , It really helped me to resolve the issue. It was issue with measure, I was replacing blank with zero. Please comment on the same, so that I can accept this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, just did that. Glad it worked out for you! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the commentary section, there are a few things that might be worth checking (it's quite a challenging question without having access to the report).

1. Is X-axis using exactly the same date field on both charts?
2. On the 1st chart, are you using a measure or a simple table filed? Perhaps your measure is returning zeros instead of blanks.
3. Your "Year to View" slicer and 1st chart fields - are they somehow linked in the data model?
4. If all of this fails, is there any small data example that you can provide us so that we can recreate the issue?